# FatalThrowableError in Handler.php line 51: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException::guards()

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

Trying to call the guards array in my auth.php file but I am getting this error that I'm calling an undefined method guards. Would really appreciate some assistance as I've been trying to solve this for quite some time now. Thank you in advance!

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401);
        }

        $guard = array_get($exception->guards(), 0);

        switch ($guard) {
            case 'admin';
                $login = 'admin/login';
                break;

            default:
                $login = 'login';
                break;
        }

        return redirect()->guest(route($login));
    }
```

Here are the contents of my auth.php file as well

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
],
```

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: @Wreigh I am using Laravel version 5.3.6

Comment: can you check this class `AuthenticationException` if it really has a `guards` method? you can check it inside `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth`

Comment: @Wreigh [5.3 have](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthenticationException.php), [5.2 don't have](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthenticationException.php).

Comment: It did not have it for some reason.. Weird, thank you Lionel for linking that code page on GitHub.. I added the code and it works now. Thank you Wreigh as well for trying to help, appreciate it guys!